# Why is Console.WriteLine not working in an MSpec assertion?

Tags: console, mspec

I'm having trouble writing to the console from an MSpec assertion. I'm using v0.5.11 (unsigned) from Nuget. Nothing radical here, but it's not working. Anyone know what I'm missing?

```
public class When_doing_stuff
{
    It should_out_stuff_to_console = () =>
    {
        var val1 = 1;
        var val2 = 2;
        (val1 + val2).ShouldEqual(3);
        Console.WriteLine(val2); 
    };
}
```

Comment: I've got the same issue, i'm outputting stuff in Establish context = () => {..};, Because of = () => {...}. The test suceeds but no output is written. The test contains one It, which passes. However, i believe i have redirected / disabled console output in a base class of my spec test. Maybe you did the same?
Also, im only running the spec test via Resharper, maybe the resharper runner doesn't show it. Will test it in console and get back to you.

Comment: Resharper 7.1 + Mspec runner 0.5.11. 
MSpec 0.5.11 nuget package. Resharper runner does not show console output, but console runner does.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you actually have a failing assertion in your real code. You posted a passing assertion, which should print just fine (as Alexander and I have both verified locally).

A failing assertion, however, throws a `SpecificationException` and the `Console` line would never be executed. You should print before your assertion. For example

```
It should_out_stuff_to_console = () => 
{
    Console.WriteLine(val2);
    (val1 + val2).ShouldEqual(3);
}
```

And the output from the `mspec` command line runner

```
cmd> mspec-clr4.exe test.dll

Specs in test:

When doing stuff
Blah
» should out stuff to console
```

But, I don't recommend printing debug statements to the console from your assertions, or your test run in general. It's going to gum up the test report (as you can see above).

Comment: Thanks Guys, I was running in resharper, and haven't tried since. Trite example, but I was trying to get something out the console for debuggnig. Writing to console was temporary, but I'll give it try.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there's nothing wrong with the assertion here, Anthony :-)

I pasted the code user287079 posted into a new Class Library, see what's being printed in my console:

```
>mspec-clr4 <somewhere>\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll

Specs in ClassLibrary1:

When doing stuff
2
» should out stuff to console


Contexts: 1, Specifications: 1, Time: 0.11 seconds
```

Comment: Oh yeah, as written it isn't a problem. I suspect that his actual problem is with a failing assertion. I think the post isn't faithfully recreating the real problem. (I updated my answer, sorry for the confusion)